# Variable as the name of a class

Tags: android, ios, flutter, class, dart

How can you use a variable as a name for a class? I want to make the name of the class flexible.

`var number = 1 ;`

`return MechanikGameStart$number();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (1 == number) return MechanikGameStart1();
else if (2 == number) return MechanikGameStart2();
// ...
```

Otherwise it's not possible in Object-oriented programming. Class name must be known and specified in advance

Comment: It has nothing to do with object-oriented programming.